# Swift - Detect if subviews of different superview intersect

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to detect if two views intersect: a view that's a subview of the main storyboard, and a subview of a subview of the main storyboard.

I tried to use `subview1.frame.intersects(subview2.frame)`, and it doesn't work. The function above always returns `false`.

As for the context, I'm trying to drag subview1 and drop it onto subview2, and detect the collision between two views upon `.Ended` state of `PanGesture`.

The view hierarchy can be expressed as the following:

```
     main view
    /         \
subview1      view2
                \
                subview2
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error? You need to provide a whole lot more information so we can even begin to answer your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without seeing your view hierarchy I can only guess that it may be that it doesn't work because .intersects compares two rects in the same coordinate space and your views probably have different coordinate spaces (unless they are siblings with the same superview, because .frame is always in your superview's coordinates).  UIView has a bunch of convert methods (you want [convertRect:fromView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622498-convertrect?language=objc)) that will transform a point or rect from one view's coordinate space to another.  Once you have both rects in the same coordinate space you can use /intersects().

```
subview1.frame.intersects(subview1.convertRect(subview2.frame, fromView: subview2))
```

Comment: Yes you are right! With minor modification to your code, I can get it working: `subview1.frame.intersects(self.view.convertRect(subview2.bounds, fromView: subview2))` will return true when the two collides. But how come using `subview1.bounds.intersects(subview2.bounds)` works too?

Answer (score 4):

I made it working by using `bounds` instead of `frame`. So by using `subview1.bounds.intersects(subview2.bounds)`, it will return `true` when I drop `subview1` onto `subview2`

According to [here](http://www.andrewgertig.com/2013/08/ios-bounds-vs-frame):

> The **bounds** of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) **relative to its own coordinate system (0,0)**.
>
> The **frame** of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) **relative to the superview** it is contained within.

I'm not sure why using a CGRect with location and size relative to its own coordinate will work when two UIViews have different parents. If someone can explain furthur I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to only detect that whether it intersects or not then just

- in Xcode `run the project`
- go to `debug tab`
- then below click on `view debugging`
- and then `show view frames`

you will see that whether these views intersect each other or not? I hope it helps.